# Как спрятать скрипт входа в админку ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Есть форма входа где требуется ввести логин/пароль, она по определенному адресу, например /root/admin/index.

Так вот, как этот путь попытаться спрятать/зашифровать/ограничивать по ip итд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотреть на роут и узнать, из чего он состоит, и поменять элементы, из которых состоит. Скорее всего, он зависит от класса и метода действия, значит, надо поменять их названия.

Answer (score 1):

1 вариант:

Запретить доступ к странице создав правило на фаерволе.

2 вариант:

Запретить доступ к странице через IIS.
Используйте функцию `"Ограничения IP адресов и доменов"`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например разрешим доступ на `/root/admin/`только локально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такой вопрос, если потом сайт заливать на сервер azure или какой-нибудь хост, эта настройка будет работать там? ну и затем без проблем по мере надобности разрешать ip адреса без перезаливки сайта снова